# C++ - a better alternative to STL's map and Boost's unordered_map?

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, hashtable

One thing that I’ve always found inconvenient about C++ programming is its lack of a good map/dictionary/hash table/associative array container class. C#, Java and Objective-C all have descent such classes, namely Dictionary<>, Hashtable and NSDictionary, that mostly work straight out of the box with all data types. But both STL’s stl::map and Boost’s boost::unordered_map are extremely clumsy and overly verbose, even for mundane everyday tasks. I was wondering if there is a C++ equivalent, in some open source library perhaps, that more closely resembles the syntax and functionality of the aforementioned platforms. 
Of the three, C#’s Dictionary<> is my favorite as it is strongly-typed, with very short syntax and very versatile. So something like that would be perfect. I’m not sure if this is possible at all. If not, I’d like to know the reasons why. Here are my main pain-points regarding Boost’s and STL’s implementations and what I’d like instead:

1. First of all, performance is not an issue here. Memory allocations, virtual function calls, O(n) complexity - it doesn't matter. Every-day dictionaries have only a few entries anyway. Ease of use is paramount.
2. The syntax should generally be like that of an array. This means a versatile operator[], like:

   dictionary[key] = value; //insertion and update
   dictionary[key] = NULL; //deletion of an element
   if(dictionary[key])  //check if the element exists. No default-constructed value should be inserted!

Java and Objective-C don’t have operator overloading so this is impossible with them. C# has it and makes an excellent use of it. Can’t C++ do the same?

1. Both values and keys can be of custom user-defined types or primitive types (ints, floats, etc.).
2. When storing user-defined objects, they should be referenced by a shared_ptr. I’m using Boost so this will be crucial in preventing memory leaks. The other three platforms are either garbage-collected (C#/Java), or have the option to choose between manual memory mgmt, reference counting and garbage collection (Objective C). Boost does a good job of implementing reference counting, so it should be possible. That’s exactly what Objective-C’s NSDictionary makes under the hood with ARC turned on.
3. When storing user-defined objects, they should be compared based on *memory address* by default. Very important: No hash functions, operator==, operator<, common base classes, etc. should be required for user-defined objects. Requiring those things could be OK to explicitly change the comparison from memory address to something else, for example by-value comparisons for strings. But most of the time we just want memory address comparisons.
4. When storing primitive data types, they should be compared by value. Whether they are wrapped/boxed in some internal object should be irrelevant to the user. Again, performance doesn’t matter.
5. Checking if a value exists with a given key should be possible with if(dictionary[key]). This SHOULD NOT insert a default constructed value object, as it does in Boost and STL.
6. Should be strongly-typed for both keys and values. So no void*. Also, no common base classes should be required for both keys and values, as this would be too intrusive and would make 3rd party classes harder to store in the map.
7. Unique keys. No null values allowed (null values cause deletion).
8. The keys should be accessible as a vector or array and traversible by index. Iterators require too much typing. That is, we should be able to write:

   for(int i = 0; i < dictionary.getKeys().getCount(); i++){
       shared_ptr value = dictionary[dictionary.getKeys()[i]];
   }

Having to write gargantuan for-loops full of iterator declarations muddles the clarity of the source code. And typedefs for iterators are no good either, as they only increase the complexity by having to “Go To Definition” for every new one you encounter, especially when reading someone else’s code.

I guess I could add some more points to the list, but I’ll just stop here. Do you know of any library with a map class that satisfies at least most of those points? I’d be very grateful for any constructive feedback.

Comment: There are no "null values" in C++. A lot of what you are asking for pre-suposes you're using a Java- or C#-like language.

Comment: This question is off topic for SO.

Comment: @juanchopanza Please elaborate

Comment: All similar C++ containers are supposed to have a similar interface, so it should be easy to switch between different containers. As for removing an entry with e.g. `dictionary[key] = NULL`, remember that in C++ `NULL` is equal to `0`, and if you have a dictionary with integer data how would you check for that? In C++03 it's not possible, in C++11 (and later) you could use `nullptr` instead, but semantically it would not be correct.

Comment: _"Every-day dictionaries have only a few entries anyway"_, wait, __wut__? Even in normal usage cases, the number of entries can be counted in hundreds, thus O(n) and O(n^2) makes a __huge__ difference. Maybe instead of describing your ideal container, tell us what do you want to use it for? Then - maybe - we can point you to a _better_ container than `map` (ex: a wrapped `vector<pair<A,B>>` can be better when you have only a few entries)?

Comment: Abstract your many for-loops into algorithms and re-use them.

Comment: I mean you can't do stuff like `dictionary[key] = NULL` because C++ doesn't have "null values". But you can say `dicitonary.erase(key)`.

Comment: @Paweł Stawarz In this particular project, those are a few dozen gesture recognizers, touch identifiers, draggable objects, and all sorts of relationships between them. But I use dictionaries in C#, Java and Objective-C all the time and it is annoying to be so inconvenient in C++.

Comment: Very very localized, even if answered would likely not provide general use to many others.

Comment: Localized? I've heard others complain about those maps as well. Anyway, based on the above points, what open-source container class is the best fit?

Comment: If you have a `map<int, int> m`, what should `m[0]` return if there is no entry for `0`?

Comment: @Jens boost::none. Oh; wait...
But that is a handy utility function to have if you're using boost.

Comment: For point 8, you could write an iterator adapter that takes a map iterator and only returns the key part when dereferences. Then you could use algorithms or a for each loop with it.

Comment: I also think that using C++ in the same way as Java or C# is not a good idea. These are different languages with different idioms.

Comment: for_each is not pretty, as you need to define a whole function just for this one loop. Unless you use lambda/anonymous functions, of course, but my compiler doesn't support C++11 (it's long story...)

Comment: I did not mean std::for_each but the C++11 for each loop. You could use BOOST_FOR_EACH though. If you happen to write the same logic over and over again ("gargantuan for-loops"), refactor them into an abstract algorithm. And when using boost, you could consider boost::bind or boost::lambda. Also check out boost pointer container library, boost algorithms and boost iterator.

Comment: Regarding #3 -- That cannot work. Comparing the address of two objects would only ever work if you were comparing the map's object with itself. If you have a `map<string, string>`, no two string objects would ever have the same address (unless, again, you explicitly retrieved the address of a string existing in the map).

Comment: Pretty much all of your complaints are trying to say you want C++ to be C#/Java. If performance is honestly not an issue, stop using a language that is all about performance and move to one of those alternatives. While I agree C++'s API could do with some better polish, most of your complaints seem to boil down to the fact that not everything is a reference (read: pointer) like it is in C#/Java. Believe me, that's a good thing.

Comment: Note: C++1y adds a `const` version of `operator[]` which throws an exception if the key is not present.

Comment: @Cdaragorn Switching to some other language is not always an option. Fun fact: C++ is the only cross-platform language when it comes to iOS/Android development, if you don't want to use a 3rd party framework. But I'm starting to consider shoehorning Lua into the development

Comment: This list is just poorly conceived: it's impossible for *any* language to have `dictionary[key]` - with arbitrary key and value types - return the value sometimes and a does-the-key-exist boolean at other times, given the value might be a boolean such that even conversion based on the context of use is inherently unreliable.  Similarly, `dictionary[key] = NULL;` inherently ambiguously matches the requested erase-the-key use and assignment use for pointer value type proposed in this question.  Builtin vs. user-defined objects: I bet you can't give a valid reason for differentiating behavior so.

Comment: Criterion 8 just shows a total lack of understanding of the implementation of associative containers - whether hash table or balanced binary tree - they *can't* be efficiently random indexed by an element numbering: a secondary index is needed and it would be crazy for any "standard" library to do that by default (very roughly, it can be expected to ~double memory usage and halve speed).  In boost there's a very configurable "multiindex" container library that automates maintenance of additional indices when actually useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will address your points one by one. In many ways, what you are asking is unrealistic for C++ (just like asking in Java for a map supporting custom operators is unrealistic).

> Here are my main pain-points regarding Boost’s and STL’s implementations and what I’d like instead:
>
> 1.First of all, performance is not an issue here. Memory allocations, virtual function calls, O(n) complexity - it doesn't matter. Every-day dictionaries have only a few entries anyway. Ease of use is paramount.

Performance is always "not an issue" until it is an issue, and when it is, it can sink your project. This is why usually, when performance is not an issue, it is good to still keep it in mind. No self-respecting library will expose a concept implementation (such as map/dictionary) with API specifications like "performance is not an issue". If there is one (though I think there shouldn't be), it will be implemented in an efficient way, or is in a library you should probably stay away from.

> 2.The syntax should generally be like that of an array. This means a versatile operator[], like:
>
> dictionary[key] = value; //insertion and update

This is already implemented C++ std::map

> dictionary[key] = NULL; //deletion of an element

This is unrealistic for C++. It can be implemented, by accessing a value through a custom reference wrapper and making that assignable with a nullptr. The problem is that in C++, a pointer is a different data type.

That is, what would this mean?

```
IdealMap<int, my_obj*> pointer_map;
pointer_map[1] = new my_obj{};
pointer_map[1] = nullptr;
```

Does the last line set poiter_map[i] to NULL, or does it ensure that any access to element i from this point will throw a "not found" exception?

You could alternately write an implementation like this:

```
IdealMap<int, my_obj*> pointer_map;
pointer_map[1] = new my_obj{};
pointer_map[1] = IdealMap<int, my_obj*>::novalue;
```

Where `novalue` would be a special constant, conceptually representing "none".

> if(dictionary[key]) //check if the element exists.

This is again, not a good idea to implement in C++ in a generic map. Consider this map:

```
IdealMap<int, bool> bool_map;
bool_map[0] = true;
if(bool_map[0]) {...}
```

Are you checking here that an element exists at position zero, or that the element is true?

> No default-constructed value should be inserted!

This is trivial to implement yourself, by encapsulating a map in a custom class.

The rest of your points sound more like a shopping list. Sorry, nobody wrote a dictionary class matching it (that is, **no, there is no library that wrote a dictionary exactly like you would like**).

> Having to write gargantuan for-loops full of iterator declarations muddles the clarity of the source code. And typedefs for iterators are no good either, as they only increase the complexity by having to “Go To Definition” for every new one you encounter, especially when reading someone else’s code.

Writing gargantuan for-loops is not something you *ever* have to do. If you have that, your problem is lack of refactoring in your code base (IMHO), not a map.

Comment: +1 for the section on performance. It is so true: performance is often "not an issue"... until it is.

Comment: The ideal container I described would probably have roughly the same performance as an NSDictionary with ARC enabled - which is not that bad at all, and even faster than Dictionary<>/Hashtable with garbage-collected object wrappers. When I said performance doesn't matter I was referring to the fact that I don't care if the underlying structure is a red-black tree, B-tree or a simple array

Comment: @OrlinGeorgiev So make a `map` containing `shared_ptr`.